# Can I export 8000+ contacts reports at once or should I use data export.io?

Tags: data-loader, data

Can I export 8000+ contacts from reports at once  or should I use dataloader.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can export 8000+ contacts from report but in the browser you only can see 2k

Comment: Would I see the all records in .csv file after exporting form reports then?

Comment: Yep not problem.